# how to get current device location when a button is pressed in xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have been trying many things that i have found but being honest i am new in xamarin.android development, i have been seeing some videos and searching for info about this, but i haven't found something like i want to do...please guys help me out, thanks in advance...have a great day

I have tried [this](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location). But i just wanna get the location when i press a button so i did the things as the github code showed me but i just made the next modification

```
private void Btngetlocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   InitializeLocationManager();
}
```

I supposed that initializing the location manager in the button.click would be enough to get what i wanned but i am getting an error when the app enters to the button...

Comment: In this knowledge base, just describe your problem.  Also, include what you thingk is most relevant from the github you refer to, so we have an idea if we can help you. And save your personal storry for your friends.

Comment: thanks for your comment #Dirk Horsten, i am just trying to get some help with this problem, like i told u i am new on this, but i thought i could find some help in here, i don't know if the calling of InitializeLocationManager(); could be in the button.click event...thanks   anyway...